# Xcode: Cannot turn off annoying code tracking feature

Tags: xcode, version-control

There seems to be a new feature in Xcode (13.4.1) in which when you edit any line in Xcode it shows you the old version of that very line. So, for example if you have the the following line of code:

`private func signOut()`

and you make some change to it, for example:

`private func signOuts()`

Now xcode shows you both the old and new lines in the following way:

[image]

I found this new feature to be absolutely annoying and confusing and I could not even figure out how to turn it off. I've tried Xcode >> Preferences >> Source Control and deselected "Show source control changes" without luck. Any ideas on how to turn this absolutely annoying feature off? Checked SO but could not find the solucion!

Comment: Just click the blue bar on the left again

Comment: If I do that I get the option to roll back my change. But that is not what I wanna do. Thank you though @aheze

Comment: Weird, is your Ctrl button stuck or is your cursor set to right click? Usually this source control preview expands/collapses when you click it

Comment: @aheze I think they are asking how to prevent it from every being offered instead of how to dismiss it once offered?

Comment: It's always sad how StackOverflow undervotes the question, which is the hard part here. Hopefully I can find this again in two years when I need it again ;)

Answer (score 6):

this was driving me crazy too! What worked for me:
View menu > Hide Code Review. Hope this helps!